# Error in pushing unique_ptrs from map into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a `std::map` of `std::string` and `std::unique_ptr<BaseInt>`. Basically I want to have a map with the class name as string `key` and a unique pointer as the corresponding `value`. And access the pointer as `map["Derived1"]` etc (explained in code below).

When I iterate over the `std::map` and try to push each `value` to a `std::vector`, I see the following error

> Error C2280 '`std::unique_ptr<BaseInt,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)`': attempting to reference a deleted function  CreateInstanceFromList  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xmemory

I am on Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.16 MSVC 14.16.27023

The implementation code is as follows. `BaseInt` is a BaseClass with an `int` member and a pure virtual `replaceInt()`. `DerivedInt1` and `DerivedInt2` implement the virtual function with different `int` values and differ by a parameter in their construction.

```
#include "UserClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseInt>> vec_type;
typedef std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseInt>> map_type;

template<typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> createInstance(vec_type& vec) { return std::make_unique<T>(); };
template<typename T, typename U> std::unique_ptr<T> createInstance(vec_type& vec, U u) { return std::make_unique<T>(u); };

void fillVector(map_type& map)
{
    vec_type my_vec;
    for (auto const& it : map )
    {
        std::cout << it.first << std::endl;
        it.second->replaceInt();

        //my_vec.emplace_back(std::move(it.second)); //this line gives error
    }
    // idea is to be able to access the pointer as map["Derived1"]
    std::cout << my_vec.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    map_type my_map;
    
    my_map.emplace("Derived1", createInstance<DerivedInt1>(my_vec, 7));
    my_map.emplace("Derived2", createInstance<DerivedInt2>(my_vec));

    fillVector(my_map);

    return 0;
}
```

My intuition is somehow I am trying to call the copyconstructor of the `unique_ptr` but I don't actually see how. Thanks.

#### Edit:

So, the main problem is the `const&` iterator as @ALX23z mentioned in the answer. The following change works:

```
    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
        it->second->replaceInt();

        my_vec.emplace_back(std::move(it->second));
    }
```

#### Edit 2:

As pointed out by multiple people, I made a basic design flaw of not using `unique_ptr` as unique. I can see the problem you mentioned and I will look into the possibility of changing to a `shared_ptr` or modifying the design. Thanks for all the quick response. I will update my changes here tomorrow.

#### Edit 3:

After looking at the main project scenarios, I can see that the `std::map` here is really just a one-time use container, so I can keep it local and pass all ownership to the `std::vector`.

#### Edit Again:

Someone downvoted the question and flagged to close it mentioning

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

I really would like them to enlighten me on how this flagging was deemed necessary. I totally presented a short code necessary to reproduce the exact problem I was facing; instead of the huge project code I am actually working on. I provided all information necessary with even my intuition of where it was failing. I added multiple edit information so that any reader can find it useful. Atleast, leave a comment and explain what can be improved. Sorry for the rant.

Comment: You need to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. Vector requires the item to be copyable and `unique_ptr`'s are not.

Comment: @uneven_mark Yeah, I added it to check possible issue, forgot to remove

Comment: Vector _does not_ require the item to be copyable, you just can't use operations that result in copying.

Comment: @lfgtm so is there no way to push into a vector without invoking copy?

Comment: I just need a way to do this without invoking copy, if possible. I would like to keep the unique_ptr.

Comment: @Anakin I don't think so, push back on vector invokes reallocation (potentially) and so items will be copied from the old mem block to new one. There are other move semantics which can come into play I think. Not too sure. however the error you get is an indication that the unique item is required to be something other than unique for that container.

Comment: @Anakin Is there a particular reason it needs to be unique. A `shared_ptr` can achieve the same. Just because it is shared, doesn't mean you can't use it in a unique way. i.e don't tell anyone it is shared ;). There is slight overhead (due to reference counting), but ultimately you can use it in a vector. Altertnatively use another container like list etc.

Comment: @lfgtm this is only a simple example of a use case in a large project. I wouldn't claim that a shared_ptr wouldn't work at all, but changing the pointer type might call for extra care in the project. That's why I said I would like to keep it the same type, if possible.

Comment: @lfgtm does using a list not invoke copy?

Comment: @Anakin Fair enough, so the next question would be, do you require a random access container (i.e vector)? If not `std::list` would be fine to use as this doesn't require reallocation of existing items when push back.

Comment: @lfgtm a `std::list` might be possible for my use case. I will have a look and get back here later. Thanks.

Comment: @lfgtm `std::vector::emplace_back` only requires the element type to be MoveInsertable, i.e. have a move constructor. It does not need to be copied, even when reallocation happens. As pointed out in the answer, the problem is the `const`ness of the reference used.

Comment: @uneven_mark Good to know, would this not require the capacity to be big enough in the first place though? At some point it might beg the question why vector is used as it's capability would be severly restricted. Should emplace_back be favoured over push_back?

Comment: @lfgtm No, the point is that when reallocation happens, each element can be *moved* to the new memory rather than needing to be *copied*. That's good enough. The same holds for `push_back`. It wouldn't make any difference in OP's code.

Comment: Are you trying to change the ownership of the objects from being owned by the map to being owned by the vector? If so, you should be moving the map to the `fillVector` function so that it's clear that its destroyed in the process.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I ended up doing that exact same thing. I pass the ownership to the vector, and the map is local and destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line gives error because you iterate over the map via a const iterator. To apply `emplace_back` on you need a non-const reference.

Also you have an error with your approach in general. `unique_ptr` is a **unique** pointer. You cannot have more than one `unique_ptr` pointing to the same object. So you cannot share them between map and a vector.

Use 2 shared_ptr, or unique_ptr with a raw pointer depending on requirements.

Comment: To be precise, the non-const reference is needed so that `std::move` actually makes the move constructor usable in `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` is the owner of the pointer, it'll delete the data when you destroy the `std::unique_ptr`.

So you don't want to have two `std::unique_ptr`'s to point to the same data because when one of them deletes your data the other one ends up pointing to something which is no longer your data. You could call `std::unique_ptr<>::release()` before deleting the `std::unique_ptr` but then it sounds like you are not using the `std::unique_ptr` correctly if you want two "unique pointers".

You could use `std::shared_ptr`. Or, what I usually do, **decide who owns the data**, vector or map, then the owner stores `std::unique_ptr`'s to data and the other stores just plain pointers. You have to make sure you deal with all the pointers before you delete the `std::unique_ptr`.

So for example:

```
typedef std::vector< BaseInt * > vec_type;
my_vec.push_back(it.second.get());
```

I haven't tried compiling but `std::unique_ptr<>::get()` returns raw pointer that is still managed by the `std::unique_ptr` in the map. Then remove from vector before removing from map, because removing from map will delete data pointed to by `std::unique_ptr`.

EDIT:

When you move the `std::unique_ptr` the ownership is transfered to the new `std::unique_ptr` so the old one no longer holds valid pointer, after you move the pointer from map to vector the map no longer has the pointer to your data:

```
my_vec.emplace_back(std::move(it->second));
```

Check what you have in map after you move pointers to vector.